# difference between circuits

Tags: flipflop, logic-gates, circuit-design

I have 2 circuits as seen below. However, I am unsure of the difference(s) between these 2 circuits. Is anyone able to help me along? Thanks in advance!

[image: circuits]

Comment: For flip flop clk need to be provide. When clock is zero is retain the   state of the Q.

Comment: Both these two circuits are drawn backwards -- by convention, inputs should come in from the left, and outputs go to the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the the final output is 'Q', select signals are also present for the mux 'S and the D Flip Flop is edge triggered .

**First Circuit**: If the select line for the mux is '1' the input will be latched to the output (Q) during the clock signal (during an edge). If the select line of the mux is '0' the previous output it will be latched to current output during the clock signal. Basically the output will be updated only during the clock. (This circuit is mainly used for synchronization).

**Second Circuit**: Here the output is instantaneous (neglecting the propagation delay of the mux). When the select line for the mux is '1'  the input will be latched to the output and when the select line is '0' the output remains the same. No need to wait for clock signal

Comment: The 2nd circuit is nonsense, isn't it? You can't build a latch using functional elements. Be aware of the poorly written questions.

Comment: @SeanHoulihane: The second circuit is a perfectly functional asynchronous latch -- just one of many ways to build one. Why would you say that this can't be done? It's curious that you describe yourself as an "ASIC designer", yet you don't know something as fundamental as this.

Comment: @DaveTweed, Fair enough - the context wasn't clear enough to me to realise that was what was inferred. I never build latches - the closest I get is models of clock gating cells, and I leave the detail of mapping that to library cells to people who only do implementation. I'll admit I have a physics degree, not an engineering degree though...